# Cant download a scorecard from pgatour.com

Tags: vba

I've searched throughout the site here to improve my simple code, but continue to have an error 424 at the set allRowofdata line, which I gleaned from here.  I'm just trying to load a golfers scorecard into my excel spread.  I appreciate any help I can get.

Here's my code:
Note:  based on advise from below, I've changed my code to the below, but now get a type mismatch error at set allRowOfData.

```
Sub Trial()


Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim allRowOfData
Dim document As Object
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False

IE.navigate "https://www.pgatour.com/players/player.32757.patton-kizzire.html/scorecards/r457"

Do Until IE.readyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop


Set allRowOfData = IE.document.getElementById("module-1510443455695-953403-17")
Dim myValue As String: myValue = allRowOfData.Cells().innerHTML


IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing


Range("A1").Value = myValue

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `appIE` ?  ....  put this at the very top of your code `Option Explicit` ..... declare your variables in upper/lower case like `dim appIE` .... then  type all your code in lowercase like `set appie =` ... if it does not change to `appIE` then you made an error

Comment: I've done as you said--error 424 is still there

Comment: you did not answer my question

Comment: that entire line was copied from a q/a here on stackover, as a way to retrieve data from a website -- i dont know its significance.

Comment: i asked what appIE is. i do not see it defined in your code. ... why would you copy a line into your code without knowing what it does?  what if it is a command to reformat your hard drive?

Comment: `"I've done as you said"`  (a) What type did you declare `appIE` as?  Was it `Dim appIE As InternetExplorer`?  Or was it `Dim appIE As Object`?  Or did you declare it as some other type?
 (b) Did you then set `appIE` to anything anywhere?  If so, was it a line saying `Set appIE = New InternetExplorer`?  Or was it `Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`? Or was it as `Set appIE = IE`?

Comment: You haven't responded to my questions (which I was hoping would cause you to have an "Ohhh!" moment), so I will just come out and say it ... you have a typo - change `appIE` to `IE`.  That should solve your object required error.

Comment: thanks YowE3K, I had changed it based on chillin's answer--now im getting the error 13 and no data, obviously.  All i want is those golf scorecards dropped into my spread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've set the page element before it gets a chance to load on the page, therefore 'allRowOfData' remains nothing.

Consider replacing this:

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
```

With:

```
Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
```

Or alternatively (inefficient but can't see any reason why it wouldn't work):

```
Do until not(allRowOfData is nothing)
Do events
Set allRowOfData = IE.document.getElementById("#module-1510443455695-953403-17")
Loop
```

The above assumes your usage of .getElementByID method is correct. Untested, written on mobile.

**Edit 1:**

See if changing this

```
Dim allRowOfData
```

To this

```
Dim allRowOfData As IHTMLElement
```

Works.

Before you re-run code, in VBA editor, click Tools > References and add a reference to the Microsoft HTML Object Library (scroll down and tick it).

Type Mismatch would suggest we're assigning something to a variable of the wrong type, so let's get rid of the implicit variant.

I haven't been able to examine the code's HTML source as I'm on mobile. It may be the case though that the specific element that you want is created subsequent to the page's initial loading (in which case you may need to use the inefficient alternative above), or that you need to iterate through a IHTMLElementCollection to get at the information. All depends on the page's structure and loading behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, chillin.  I've followed your advice, and it's changed my error, at least.  Now I get an error "13 - type mismatch" at the Set allRowofdata line.

Comment: Okay, delete this line completely from your code: Dim document As Object. Now re-run and check whether you still get an error.